# Magento Version 1.9.2 Clicked System in Admin and Receive Error:Invalid config field backend model: backup/config_backend_cron

Tags: adminhtml, cron, backup

I have everything running pretty well on my Magento site, but I keep running into this weird error when I click Configuration -> Advanced -> System

I have been searching for hours now trying to figure out the solution. I see a lot of people usually have a file missing or php class, but I have the app/code/core/Mage/Backup and associated files inside the folder along with the proper files in accordance. Per standards, you don't touch the Mage core files. So any ideas???

```
a:5:{i:0;s:62:"Invalid config field backend model: backup/config_backend_cron";i:1;s:1748:"#0 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
#1 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#4 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#5 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#6 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#7 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/dev/cpi-magento/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:104:"/dev/cpi-magento/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/system/key/d4cb4bbf89cbd80524f1e1527eaaf549/";s:11:"script_name";s:26:"/dev/cpi-magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, found that my server did not have write access to my exception.log and system.log. Found it was missing the app/code/core/Mage/Backup/Model/Config/Backend folder and associated files causing the error. For you new users, make sure your log files are read and writable! Holy helps so much for debugging things. It told me what was missing.